# pyrocms page throwing error 500

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, pyrocms

I installed pyrocms on a clients server with godaddy, its regular hosting and he has multiple domains linked to folders.
when i navigate to the site, the homepage opens up properly, the links to the other pages like the contact page the links are wrong, i have

> http://thebellsschools.org/thebellsschools/site/index.php/contact

instead of

> http://thebellsschools.org/site/index.php/contact

Am also using the default .htaccess file that ships with pyrocms

```
# Multiple Environment config
# Set this to development, staging or production
# SetEnv PYRO_ENV production

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    # disable the Apache MultiViews directive if it is enabled on the server. It plays havoc with URL rewriting
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    # Automatically determine and set the PYRO_ENV variable
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.domain.com$
  #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:development]

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage.domain.com$
  #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:staging]

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
  #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production]

    # NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
    #AllowOverride All
    #RewriteBase /wherever/pyro/is

    # Restrict your site to only one domain
    # !important USE ONLY ONE OPTION

    # Option 1: To rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Option 2: To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Where are you seeing the error 500, the subpages?  Anyway you definitely want to get hold of the error log - which apparently for Godaddy you can enable here - http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1197/working-with-error-logs - realistically for PyroCMS you need a hosting provider that provides this as you can run into all kinds of weird issues…